# Plotly in Python: How to add legend when using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

In plotly, you can convert a matplotlib figure into plot.ly:

x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y,label='test')
fig=plt.gcf()

[image]

However, if I add legend,

```
x=[1,2,3]
y=[4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y,label='test')
fig=plt.gcf()
plt.legend()
```

It will return error `RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer`

I want to know what is the problem? Does plot.ly support legend made with matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `showlegend=True` to your `plt.plot(x,y,label='test')` could do the trick.